# PostgreSQL: Joining the count of another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I have three tables: `users`, `items`, and `boards`.

```
create table users (
    id serial primary key,
    name text
);  

create table items (
    id serial primary key,
    user_id int,
    title text
);  

create table boards (
    id serial primary key,
    user_id int,
    title text
);n
```

I want to select all the users with the number of items and boards each user has:

```
select
    users.*,
    count(items) as item_count,
    count(boards) as board_count
from users
    left join items on items.user_id = users.id
    left join boards on boards.user_id = users.id
group by users.id;
```

Unfortunately, this does not give me the right counts. The counts are way higher than they should be. What is happening, why, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is caused by fact that two left joins produce duplicate values.

To solve this you can either count only distinct values

```sql
SELECT u.id, u.name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) item_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) board_count
  FROM users u LEFT JOIN items i
    ON u.id = i.user_id LEFT JOIN boards b
    ON u.id = b.user_id
 GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```

or count items and boards per user separately and then join them with users

```sql
SELECT u.*, 
       COALESCE(i.item_count, 0) item_count, 
       COALESCE(b.board_count, 0) board_count
  FROM users u LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) item_count
    FROM items
   GROUP BY user_id
) i ON u.id = i.user_id LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) board_count
    FROM boards
   GROUP BY user_id
) b ON u.id = b.user_id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f4928/5)** demo

Comment: With a primary key on users.id, you can take name out of the group by in the first query. The second query ought to be the most efficient, of course.

Comment: peterm you wouldn't happen to be the guy on robot game would you?

Comment: @Brandon No I'm not the guy. But I'm not sure is it good or bad? ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do the trick

```
select
    u.*,
    (select count(*) from items where user_id = u.id) as item_count,
    (select count(*) from boards where user_id = u.id) as board_count
from users as u
group by u.id;
```

Comment: The group-by in the last line is not required.

Comment: ... and not as efficient a method as joining to pre-aggregated result sets, unless you only wanted a very small subset of users included.